# How to add a picture onto an existing pdf file?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, editing

My OS is Ubuntu. So I prefer Linux/Debian software, but any Windows software that can run under Wine or mono would be okay too.

I have a scanned pdf file which is [an application form](https://docs.google.com/file/d/1tqjgoFeXuKOBvXDncBGa3ozY8Nbe_2AXZ5Go3SKatOP47iCyzhm-A5OTR9PP/edit?pli=1), and a picture which is the scanned version of one's signature (for example, [this one](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Autograph_of_Benjamin_Franklin.svg/200px-Autograph_of_Benjamin_Franklin.svg.png)) and can be in any image format such as eps or png. I would like to put the signature picture on the blank space right to "APPLICANT:" on the second page of the application form. I wonder how to do that?

I have tried the following methods, but none succeeded.

1. The first way is using gimp. I first import the application form
   into gimp, and then paste the signature picture on the space right
   to "APPLICANT:" on the second page of the application form.

   But the
   problems are that:

   - It seems that I can only import one page of the
     application form into gimp, not all of the two pages.
   - Also when I
     save the modification, the closest format to pdf I can save to is
     ps, and the resolution has been downgraded and the storage size of
     the saved file is 10 times bigger than the original application form and the signature picture.
2. The second way is using Libreoffice Draw. I have installed  the
   libreoffice-pdfimport package. But after I import the application
   form into Libreoffice Draw,

   - all the scanned content is not imported,
     and
   - the layout is different from the layout of the original
     application form.

So what other ways can I try? I would prefer some way that can lay the signature picture directly on the application form pdf file,

- without having to convert between formats,
- without having to create much bigger files while keeping the original resolution,
- without having to split and combine pages of a multi-page pdf file,
- without having to rasterize other parts of the pdf file, i.e. without losing the text I later added to the application form pdf file by having to convert the whole pdf into images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I would do it like this:

1. Create a blank page PDF with just the signature in the lower left corner on it. If you wanna be fancy, make the signature blue or red or green.... **Important:** the page should use a *transparent* background, not a white one! Keep this around as the "master-sig.pdf".
2. Use Ghostscript to convert the "master-sig.pdf" into a new "working-sig.pdf" page, with the signature shifted to the spot where you need it:

   ```
   gs -o working-sig.pdf \
      -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
      -c "<< /PageOffset [216 504] >> setpagedevice" \
       master-sig.pdf
   ```

   This one would shift the signature by 3 inches to the left, and 7 inches to the top (72 points in PostScript == 1 inch on a ruler). *You'll have to experiment a bit, or apply a hardware ruler on the piece of paper printout (plus some algebra) to determine the correct numbers.*
3. Use `pdftk` to overlay the "working-sig.pdf" onto your "contract.pdf" with the result as "signed-contract.pdf"

   ```
   pdftk \
       contract.pdf \
       stamp   working-sig.pdf \
       output  signed-contract.pdf
   ```

Comment: In the current version of Ghostscript (9.50), I've had to tweak the command line syntax to make the first command work (your mileage may vary), I had to add `-f` before the input argument: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o working-sig.pdf -c "<< /PageOffset [216 504] >> setpagedevice" -f master-sig.pdf`.

Comment: You can combine 1 and second step using ghostscrip too `gs -o A4-image.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g5950x8420 -r300x300 -c "<</PageOffset [100 500]>> setpagedevice" -f image.pdf` whereabout -g is resolution in pixel width/height -r is DPI and PageOffset is left bottom, units in points

Answer (score 6):

This was annoying me, so I made a small package called `pdfstamp` to make it easier.

https://github.com/benwinding/pdfstamp

**Install**

`npm i -g pdfstamp`

**Ensure you have dependencies (`ImageMagick` and `pdftk`)**

`pdfstamp doctor`

**Usage**

```
pdfstamp stamp \                                                                                                      
--input ./input.pdf \                                                                                  
--signature ./signature.png \                                                      
--output ./output.pdf \                                
--page 2 \                       
--bottom 300 \
--left 200
```

[image]

Comment: Love the idea, and I upvoted. But I found some bugs. Positioning is not really working unless I zoom to 100%. Also the "doctor" mode doesn't really work.

Comment: Thanks PJ, will hopefully get time to fix it soon 

Answer (score 5):

The LibreOffice provided answers don't keep the appearance of the text.

Use LibreOffice Writer, but this way:

1. Create a new LibreOffice Writer document;
2. Remove margins through Format → Page;
3. Import each PDF page through Insert → Image;
4. You can lay any image over the inserted (original) ones.

Comment: straight forward, easily available. Thanks.
Addition: Nowadays in Draw there is no Format->Page anymore. You have to search for slide and adjust the paper size and margin there.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfedit
```

To start PDFEdit, type:

```
$ pdfedit /path/to/pdf.file &
$ pdfedit &
```

This will give you use of a PDF editor to fix your problem.

This [software](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-source-linux-pdf-writer.html) is a WYSIWYG visual editor that also supports scripting and almost anything can be scripted. PDFedit is a low-level tool for users. You can use this software:

To write / create / edit PDF files.

Print PDF files.

Save PDF files.

Export PDF files to XML etc.

Comment: Can you please give a short description of how `pdfedit` works, to solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks! As @Randolph said, could you explain how pdfedit can add a picture onto an existing pdf file?

Comment: pdfedit is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2018, pdfedit is no longer in any repositories, but happily [LibreOffice Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) (likely installed on Ubuntu already, or easy to get through your distribution's package manager) now works very well to edit text on most PDFs (for instance to fill in forms) and to insert images (for instance to paste in your signature).

Comment: Exporting to PDF from LibreOffice Draw doesn't keep the original PDF links working.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about LibreOffice Draw.  Use LibreOffice Writer.  I've got the entire process written in a blog post over at http://colans.net/blog/signing-document-image-ubuntu-1210 .

Comment: The tutorial presents LibreOffice Draw and not Writer. Anyway, on my computer LibreOffice automatically switches to Draw when I want to open a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently (January 2024) [reviewed the alternatives for PDF editing in Linux](https://maker-help.blogspot.com/2024/01/editing-pdfs-in-windows-and-linux.html), and I'm happy to say that at last we have an effective user-friendly option: [Xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp), *“a handwriting notetaking software with PDF annotation support”.* PDF rendering support is excellent, and the UI is comparable to that of LibreOffice Draw. The only warning is that you should definitely install the latest stable release, since even slightly outdated versions tend to be a little buggy. This is especially true for Ubuntu LTS and derivatives which tend to trail behind upstream repositories.

To install the latest stable release of Xournal++ to Ubuntu, open a terminal session and enter the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

Once Xournal++ is installed, PDF files can be opened from the main menu by selecting *File -> Open,* or by using the **Ctrl+O** shortcut. Common editor options include:

- Add Image: *Tools -> Image* or **Shift+Ctrl+I** — then click on the location where you want to add an image. A file selection dialog will automatically open. Once the image is added it can be freely moved and scaled. If you want to scale an image while keeping its proportion, click and drag one of the corners of the image bounding box; to scale without maintaining proportion, click and drag from the middle of one of the sides.
- Add Text: *Tools -> Text* or **Shift+Ctrl+T** — then click on the location where you want to add a text box. Font face, size and effects (i.e. italic and / or bold) can be selected from a tool bar drop down. The text box expands in response to the amount of text; line breaks can be added manually.
- Select Rectangle: *Tools -> Select Rectangle* or **Shift+Ctrl+R** — allows previously added elements to be selected, moved and copied / pasted (with **Ctrl+C** / **Ctrl+V**).

Notice that when a tool is selected, it remains active until something else is selected — for example, if *Add Image* is selected, the file selection dialog will open every time you click the document. It's good practice to manually revert to *Select Rectangle* every time a new element is added to the document, to avoid surprises.

After completing the desired edits, *File -> Export as PDF* can be used to export the whole document with the changes. To export just the modifed page(s), you can use *File -> Print,* select *Print to File* and specify the desired page(s). Also remember to set the destination file path, which defaults to `~/Documents/output.pdf`.

Comment: Great answer! Just wanted to add that ``sudo apt install xournalpp'' is enough, as the official repositories include the latest stable version.

Comment: Back when I posted this answer the version in the official Ubuntu repository had a bug in the *Add Image* feature, which would sometimes cause images to be duplicated whenever they were moved or resized. That's why I recommend installing from the project repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a reasonably good experience with [uPdf](https://launchpad.net/updf).

#### Installation

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/updf
sudo apt-get update
suod apt-get install -y updf
```

Then fix a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/updf/+bug/1180103) by [editing 2 lines in a Python script](https://bugs.launchpad.net/updf/+bug/1180103/comments/2).

#### Usage

Launch uPdf, select the *Add an image* tool, draw a rectangle around the area where you want the signature to go and select the image file with your signature. A PNG with a transparent background works best.

Answer (score -1):

Use [pdflatex/xelatex/lualatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). These programs can read images and pdfs and create new pdfs.

Comment: My question is that how do you place the picture at some particular location on the pdf file?

Comment: @Tim: Put one picture in the background and put the other on top of it; the `picture` environment and the `textpos` package can do that. I suggest to take your question to http://tex.stackexchange.com .

Comment: [There you go](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64634/how-to-add-a-picture-onto-an-existing-pdf-file)

Comment: Very lazy answer, would downvote if I could.